# Updating blacklist.js file

Tags: react-native

Why do I need to rewrite code by changing default.js file from proj_name/node_modules\metro-config\src\defaults
 for every project that I create?
Is there any permanent solution for this issue?

```
var sharedBlacklist = [
  /node_modules[\/\\]react[\/\\]dist[\/\\].*/,
  /website\/node_modules\/.*/,
  /heapCapture\/bundle\.js/,
  /.*\/__tests__\/.*/
];
```

above is updated

```
var sharedBlacklist = [
  /node_modules[/\\]react[/\\]dist[/\\].*/,
  /website\/node_modules\/.*/,
  /heapCapture\/bundle\.js/,
  /.*\/__tests__\/.*/
];
```

this is to be updated

I have to do this every time I create new project.

Comment: Why do you need to update?

Comment: I get following error every time I type command "react-native start"
and solution to this error is changing above file.
---------
error Invalid regular expression: /(.*\\__fixtures__\\.*|node_modules[\\\]react[\\\]dist[\\\].*|website\\node_modules\\.*|heapCapture\\bundle\.js|.*\\__tests__\\.*)$/: Unterminated character class. Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: /(.*\\__fixtures__\\.*|node_modules[\\\]react[\\\]dist[\\\].*|website\\node_modules\\.*|heapCapture\\bundle\.js|.*\\__tests__\\.*)$/: Unterminated character class

Comment: I found this which looks like it should fix it:  https://github.com/facebook/metro/pull/468

Today is my first look at React Native so not sure how I get this fix into my project though.  :)